# PHP valid http statuses

Tags: php

On my website users can enter a HTTP status code into a standard text input field. i.e, 200, 400, 404, 403 etc...

Is there any way to check if the HTTP status code is valid. For example if a user enters '123' it will return false. I currently cannot think of or find a way other than doing a large ugly if or switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built-in functions to achieve this in PHP, but a less verbose way for a check than an `if` or `switch` statement could be the use of an array:

```
$validStatusCodes = [200, 201, 202, ...];

if (in_array($submittedStatusCode, $validStatusCodes)) {
    // Ok
} else {
    // Not ok
}
```

Comment: At http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#107261 you can find a switch with most of the status codes

Answer (score 5):

For those using *Symfony* or *Laravel*, you can do the following :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

function is_valid_http_status(int $code) : bool {
    // thanks @James in the comments ^^
    return array_key_exists($code, Response::$statusTexts);
}
```

Assuming that `Response` is one of those:

- `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`
- `Illuminate\Http\Response`

Comment: `array_key_exists($code, Response::$statusTexts)`

Answer (score 4):

According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) the following `HTTP/1.1` status codes are valid:

```
$status_code = array("100","101","200","201","202","203","204","205","206","300","301","302","303","304","305","306","307","400","401","402","403","404","405","406","407","408","409","410","411","412","413","414","415","416","417","500","501","502","503","504","505");

if(in_array("404", $status_code)){
    echo "valid";
  }else{
    echo "invalid";
  }
```